# how can I change the kivy's "on_touch_down" function to work only when clicking certain widgets?

Tags: python, kivy

here is my code:

it suppose to create an mouse app, the touchpad button is suppose to activate a function that sends coordinates to a server. I want it to stop sending coordinates when the touchpad is released.

```
class Touch(Widget):
    btn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def send_movement(self, message):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as d:
            d.sendto(message.encode(), (HOST, 5555))

    def movement(self, instance):
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        new_x, new_y = pyautogui.position()
        dif_x, dif_y = new_x - x, new_y - y
        self.send_movement(f'{dif_x},{dif_y}')

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.btn.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.movement(None)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.movement(None)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Touch, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(text='Touchpad')
        self.btn.bind(on_touch_down=self.on_touch_down,
                      on_touch_move=self.on_touch_move,
                      on_touch_up=self.on_touch_up)
        self.add_widget(self.btn)

class MyApp(App):
    @staticmethod
    def send_click(message):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect((HOST, PORT))
            s.sendall(message.encode())

    @staticmethod
    def send_movement(message):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as d:
            d.sendto(message.encode(), (HOST, 5555))

    def left_button_pressed(self, instance):
        self.send_click("left")

    def right_button_pressed(self, instance):
        self.send_click("right")

    def touchpad_pressed(self, instance):
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        self.send_click(f"{x},{y}")

    def touchpad_released(self, instance):
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        self.send_click(f"n{x},{y}")

    def movement(self, instance):
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        new_x, new_y = pyautogui.position()
        dif_x, dif_y = new_x - x, new_y - y
        self.send_movement(f'{dif_x},{dif_y}')

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',
                           size_hint=(None, None),
                           size=(400, 400),
                           spacing=10,
                           padding=20,
                           pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})

        lr_buttons = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                               size_hint=(None, None),
                               size=(200, 50),
                               pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
        left_button = Button(text='Left', on_press=self.left_button_pressed)
        right_button = Button(text='Right', on_press=self.right_button_pressed)
        lr_buttons.add_widget(left_button)
        lr_buttons.add_widget(right_button)

        touch_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal',
                                 size_hint=(None, None),
                                 size=(360, 200),
                                 pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
        touch = Touch()
        touch_layout.add_widget(touch)

        layout.add_widget(lr_buttons)
        layout.add_widget(touch_layout)

        return layout


try:
    MyApp().run()
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print('Server is not connected')
```

I tried to add the

```
if self.btn.collide_point(*touch.pos):
```

check in the *on_touch_down func* but it didnt work.

when I click any part of the screen it activates the *movement* function